# SSIS Fuzzy Grouping Always return the same result with different similarity thrshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, fuzzy-comparison

Can anyone tell me why my similarity is always 1.

My goal is **AAB** and **AAC** can be set as the same group for example.

Thanks

[image: This is Result]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After I tried different source data, I got the goal what I need.
I think for sample data, it should be better to use some real example in the world.
Instead of AAA and AAC, maybe use Name column like Sara vs Saraa then ssis would say they are in the same group. However, i found for Don vs Done, they won't. So....it may not good idea to filter the records that has typo with different letter?

*** try to create more than one column to be you comparison column